# `filetype plugin on` and square brackets

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, filetype

With this `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap [ :lp^M
nnoremap ] :lne^M
filetype plugin on
```

`vim` becomes sluggish when switching between "errors" of location list with square brackets. As opposed to using `lprevious`/`lnext` directly. The same goes for mapping brackets to `cprevious`/`cnext`.

Everything is okay without enabling filetype plugins (just `filetype on`). Or if `filetype plugin on` is executed after `vim` has started. Or if `vim` is started as follows: `vim -u ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: The ftplugin for your language probably has mapping starting with `[` and `]` which may explain that sluggishness: if you have something mapped to `]]` ("next method" in python files), for example, Vim will wait a bit in order to see if you want `]` or `]]`.

Comment: Indeed, you're [right](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/vim7.4/ftplugin/ruby.vim#L149-165). First, if you post an answer, I'll accept it. Also, can you explain by any chance why everything is fine if `filetype plugin on` is executed after `vim` has started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@romainl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3357/filetype-plugin-on-and-square-brackets#comment4692_3357), it turns out the delay is caused by ftplugin [defining](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/vim7.4/ftplugin/ruby.vim#L149-165) mappings starting with `[`.